# Strip characters from the ansible output

Tags: ansible, stdout

Is there a way to strip the code linux "**\u001b[32m** ACTIVE **\u001b[0m**" from the output lines and remaining ACTIVE or DISABLED?

```
ok: [server-c] => {
    "msg": [
        "Certificates 1\"                                     \u001b[32mACTIVE\u001b[0m", 
        "Certificates 2\"                                     \u001b[32mACTIVE\u001b[0m", 
        "Certificates 3\"                                     \u001b[32mACTIVE\u001b[0m", 
        "Certificates 4\"                                     \u001b[93mDISABLED\u001b[0m", 
        "Certificates 5\"                                     \u001b[93mDISABLED\u001b[0m", 

    ]
}
```

I tried with my ansible code but doesn't strip anything :

```
---
- hosts: server
  become: yes
  become_user: user
  tasks:
   - name: Show certificates   
     shell: '/bin/bash -i -c "kb | grep -i  certificates"' 
     register: results 
   - debug: msg="{{ results.stdout_lines | replace('\\u001b[32m', '') | replace('\\u001b[93m', '') | replace('\\u001b[0m', '') }}"
```

Comment: Try ``replace('\\u001b.*0m', '')``

Answer (score 1):

For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item|regex_replace('\\u001b.*0m', '')|trim }}"
      loop: "{{ results.stdout_lines }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Certificates 1"
  msg: Certificates 2"
  msg: Certificates 3"
  msg: Certificates 4"
  msg: Certificates 5"
```

---

If you want to remove the part of the line after the quote

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item|regex_replace(_regex, '') }}"
      loop: "{{ results.stdout_lines }}"
      vars:
        _regex: '".*0m'
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Certificates 1
  msg: Certificates 2
  msg: Certificates 3
  msg: Certificates 4
  msg: Certificates 5
```